# If $\lim_{x\to x_{0}} f(x) = L$ and $\lim_{x\to x_{0}}g(x)=\infty $, then $\lim_{x\to x_{0}}(f(x) + g(x)) = \infty$

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, solution-verification

regarding proving this claim:

If $\lim_{x\to x_{0}} f(x) = L$ and $\lim_{x\to x_{0}}g(x)=\infty $, then $\lim_{x\to x_{0}}(f(x) + g(x)) = \infty$

I am at the end of the proof, right here:

$f(x)+g(x) > L - \square_{1} + \square_{2} \geq  K $

I don't know what to place inseatd of $\square_{1}$ and $\square_{2}$.

I know that $\square_{1}>0$ because it represent $\varepsilon$.

In $\square_{2}$ I tried placing $K$...

Any help will be awesome!

Thank you so much!

Comment: The first box can be anything you want, then the second box will be in terms of K,L, and whatever you wrote for the first box (if you want you may for example plus 1 to that)

Comment: So if I chose K for the first box, what do I choose for the second one?

Answer (score 1):

For it to tend to $\infty$ we need that $\forall\ K>0, \exists\ \delta>0: x\in B_\delta(x_0)\implies f(x) > K$.
Let K > 0.
If you're close enough to $x_0$ ($\delta_1(\varepsilon)$), then $f(x)> L-\varepsilon$ and if you're close enough to $x_0$ ($\delta_2(R)$) then $g(x)> R$.
so if $x\in B_{min(\delta_1,\delta_2)}(x_0)$ we have that$f(x)+g(x)> L-\varepsilon+R > K \iff R> K-L+\varepsilon$
Note that you can thus choose $R$ so that it fulfills that.

**EDIT**:
Given that my original answer produced some confusion. Let's do it being a little more careful. Perhaps this way you can see it more clearly.
We need to prove $$\operatorname{lim}_{x\rightarrow x_0} (f(x)+g(x)) = +\infty$$
That means that $\forall \ K>0, \exists\ \delta>0: x\in B_\delta(x_0)\implies f(x) > K$
Someone gives you $K>0$, now you have to find a $\delta$ that works for that K. Take $\varepsilon=1$, and $R=K-L+2$.
Since $g(x)\rightarrow \infty $ then there is a $\delta_1>0: x\in B^*_{\delta_1}(x_0) \implies g(x)>R$, by definition of the limit. Now, since $f(x) \rightarrow L$. Then there is a $\delta_2>0: x\in B^*_{\delta_2}(x_0)\implies |f(x)-L|<\varepsilon \implies f(x)>L-\varepsilon$.

Take $\delta = min \lbrace\delta_1,\delta_2\rbrace$ then if $x\in B^*_{\delta}(x_0) \implies f(x)+g(x)>L-\varepsilon+R = K+1 > K$
So we have what we wanted

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Yes, this is what I am looking for, to find this "$R$," but I do need to choose a specific "$R$", and not conditioned one.

Comment: given K, choose R = K-L+$\varepsilon$ + 1 and you have what you want

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking to something more simple than that :)

Comment: @Math4me That's actually quite simple as it stands already.

Comment: I think that K-L can be negative, which is not true.

Comment: The condition on R>0 is actually not needed, it is valid for $R\in\mathbb{R}$, one usually uses R>0, because that is what one wants or because one is concerned with |f|. The proof I gave is correct even if K-L is negative. Choose $R= max(K-L+\varepsilon+1, 1+\varepsilon)$ in any case

Comment: Check yourself mate, it can not be.

Comment: i've edited it to be clearer